# OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Error

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I was playing with the TTS libs and when I was using pyttsx3, it showed me this error

```
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But, I have already downloaded libespeak1 through the terminal. I am using Linux mint and Python 3. I am using Pycharm as IDE. I browsed many forums but, every one of them said I had to install the lib. But, I have done it already.

Comment: where is `libespeak.so.1` on your disk? What is the output of `'sudo echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH' `?

Comment: Don’t know. I just installed it through the terminal

Comment: come back with the information I have asked you to find in the previous comment.

Comment: What should I type in the terminal? 'sudo echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH' is not going to work right?

Comment: I have the same issue: 
- Works in commandline, fails in Pycharm
- same virtualenv for both 

Pycharm 2021.1  //  python 3.9.2


Pycharm doesn't like this when you try to initialize it: 
`engine = pyttsx3.init()`

Comment: @JamesLiu Try installing pyttx from PyCharm